# django syntax inside javascript

Tags: javascript, django, templates, syntax

Ive been trying to work around it all weekend.
i cant seem to figure out how to load a static image when im inside a script tag in a Django template.

if you look at this code. the image loads properly.
but wehn trying to do the same thing through javascript it does not work.

Ive read some of the other posts but they all talk about using variables inside javascript.
and none talk about the {% static %} syntax.

this is the code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load dictionary_extras %}

{% block content %}
        <img src={% static 'lol2.jpg' %}>
        <canvas id="e" width="320" height="200" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            document.write('hello world.');
            var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj,0,0);
            };
            imageObj.src = {% static 'lol2.jpg' %};
        </script>
{% endblock %}
```

thanks!

Comment: please not I edited above and added the single missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between using Django template tags in HTML and inside Javascript code in your templates.

Make sure your Javascript code is correct and that it's not failing just because you forgot to add single quotes:

```
{% static 'lol2.jpg' %}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. Although this seems to not work. Yes i had forgotten the quotes i guess while i was editing the code at some point. but it still does not work. THere seems to be a clear difference cause my <img> tag works with loading the picture. but the latter does not

Comment: something seems to be wrong with that line. the one that has imageObj.src = {% static 'lol2.jpg' %} . if i exlude it from the javascript code. the document.write command works and displays on the page. but only if i comment that line out. otherwise that whole block does not work and document.write does not write anything to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, make sure you got quotes around the tag:

```
imageObj.src = "{% static 'lol2.jpg' %}";
```

When you use `static` tag it renders the full url, but in order for it to be proper JavaScript or HTML tag it also needs to be surrounded by quotes, ex:

```
<img src={% static 'lol2.jpg' %}>
```

renders to (depending on your STATIC_URL setting):

```
<img src=/static/lol2.jpg>
```

where it should be:

```
<img src="{% static 'lol2.jpg' %}">
```

which will render to:

```
<img src="/static/lol2.jpg">
```